# ROS topic tools mux not registering my output when I roslaunch the mux node

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Very strange error and I have a workaround by simply adding another topic, and then manually selecting it from the using the MuxSelect service. It is just a minor annoyance.

According to the package documentation (http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux), the arguments are as follows:

```
mux <outopic> <intopic1> [intopic2...] [standard ROS arguments]
```

launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
    <node pkg="topic_tools" type="mux" name="mux_cmd_vel" args="cmd_vel move_base/cmd_vel joy/cmd_vel mux:=mux_cmd_vel"/>
</launch>
```

rosnode info /mux_cmd_vel  outputs:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/mux_cmd_vel]
Publications: 
 * /mux_cmd_vel/selected [std_msgs/String]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /clock [unknown type]
 * /joy/cmd_vel [unknown type]
 * /move_base/cmd_vel [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /cmd_vel_select
 * /mux_cmd_vel/add
 * /mux_cmd_vel/delete
 * /mux_cmd_vel/get_loggers
 * /mux_cmd_vel/list
 * /mux_cmd_vel/select
 * /mux_cmd_vel/set_logger_level


contacting node http://amr:42221/ ...
Pid: 20173
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound (52187 - 10.27.159.119:47390) [11]
    * transport: TCPROS
```

Problem here is cmd_vel is supposed to show up as an output topic but it does appear in Publications when I use "rosnode info", nor does it appear in "rostopic list".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385853/ros-topic-tools-mux-not-registering-my-output-when-i-roslaunch-the-mux-node/) by [Randombs](https://answers.ros.org/users/52210/randombs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you dive into the code of the `mux` node [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/tools/topic_tools/src/mux.cpp), you will see that the publisher is only advertised when the first message from any of the subscribed topics is received.

Therefore, if you are not publishing to `move_base/cmd_vel`, and `joy/cmd_vel` after launching / starting the `mux` node, you will not see `cmd_vel` in the `rostopic list` output, or in the `rosnode info` output. You should be able to see `cmd_vel` topic in the `rostopic list` output, or in the `rosnode info` output after you start publishing to  `move_base/cmd_vel`, and `joy/cmd_vel` topics.

I can see that when you executed the `rosnode info`, the incoming topics had no publishers (as all subscriptions are of `[unknown type]`.

So run the `mux` node as usual, play the rosbag (I assume you are playing with rosbags because your `use_sim_time` param is set to `true` which is why the `mux` node is subscribing to `/clock` topic, in which case do not forget `rosbag play --clock <bag_name>`), wait for messages to be published (`mux` node should log something like following)

```
[ INFO] [1630900837.305035517]: advertising
```

Now you should be able to see `cmd_vel` in the `rostopic list` output and in the `rosnode info` output.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2021-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Randombs](https://answers.ros.org/users/52210/randombs/) on 2021-09-06**:
Yes you're right, thank so so much for the detailed explanation. This was very helpful!